# Opening a view via another event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several views that need to be opened, but I don't want to repeat the code.  Currently each button triggers something like this:

```
private void icon_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewName var = new viewName();
    var.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Ideally, I'd like something like this (but don't know what type of variable/object I should use):

```
private void icon_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenView(viewName)
}

private voice OpenView(?????? newView)
{
    newView var = new newView();
    var.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated (yet again).

Comment: Do all the views have a default constructor like that? And is this a WinForms application?

Comment: Sorry about that....  It's a WPF app and pretty much (although I may add a few extra variables at a later point).

Comment: Could you add the WPF tag to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it with Reflection by using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator.createinstance).

```
private void icon_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenView(typeof(viewName));
}

private void OpenView(Type newView)
{
    if(typeof(Window).IsAssignableFrom(newView)) {
        Window window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(newView);
        window.Show();
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

This means you'll pass the Type of Window you'd like to open to the OpenView method. This method creates an instance by using the default constructor. It will then call Show and Close on the created Window. The IF before all that is meant to check whether the passed Type *is a* Window.

It is also possible to pass constructor arguments to CreateInstance, in case you don't have a default constructor on every Window.

I hope that makes some sense.